# multiple parameters call back in Moq

Tags: callback, moq

Can someone please look at the code below and see what's wrong?

```cs
[TestInitialize]
public void SetupMockRepository()
{
    var memberId = "34345235435354545345";
    var title = "test";
    var url = "dafdsfdsfdsfdsafd";

    _mockPropertySearchRepository = new Mock<IPropertySearchRepository>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    _mockPropertySearchRepository
        .Setup(p => p.SaveSearchURL(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Callback<string,string,string>((id,t,u) =>  )
            .Returns(new SavedSearchReturnResult() );

}
```

Thanks

Comment: I cant pass 3 parameters to the callback.

Comment: belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 50):

I managed to solve the problem myself as below

```cs
[TestInitialize]
public void SetupMockRepository()
{
    var memberId = "34345235435354545345";
    var title = "test";
    var url = "dafdsfdsfdsfdsafd";


    _mockPropertySearchRepository = new Mock<IPropertySearchRepository>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    _mockPropertySearchRepository
        .Setup(p => p.SaveSearchURL(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Callback<string,string,string>(
            (id, t, u) =>
            {
                memberId = id;
                title = t;
                url = u;
            })
        .Returns(new SavedSearchReturnResult());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For each parameter that the method takes, pass a type parameter to the `Callback` method.

```cs
someMock
    .Protected()
    .Setup("SomeMethod", ItExpr.IsAny<string>(), ItExpr.IsAny<string>())
    .Callback<string, string>((x, y) => {});
```

The above works both with `Protected` and normal callbacks.