# How to change input parameter in Moq?

Tags: c#, moq

Consider

```
var list = new List<string>();
someObject.AddOne(list);
Assert.AreEqual(1, list.Count);
```

How can I setup my mock? I expect

```
var mock = new Mock<SomeObject>();
var list = new List<string>();
mock
    .Setup(so => so.AddOne(list))
    .Callback<List<string>>(l => l.Add("derp"));
```

to work, but the callback does not get called.

I cannot change SomeObject, since this is an external API I use.

Comment: Why do you need to mock the input? If you need to test adding to the list you only need to mock only out parametres.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This test will succeed:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace UnitTestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest
    {
        public class SomeObject
        {
            public virtual void AddOne(List<string> aList) { }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void SomeTest()
        {
            // Arrange
            var mock = new Mock<SomeObject>();

            mock.Setup(so => so.AddOne(It.IsAny<List<string>>()))
                .Callback<List<string>>(l => l.Add("derp"));

            var target = mock.Object;
            var list = new List<string>();

            // Act
            target.AddOne(list);

            // Assert
            Assert.IsTrue(list.Contains("derp"));            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the syntax look like when there is two parameters and you would only want to add an entry to the second parameter and not change the first parameter?

Comment: @Janneman96 Have a loot at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627945/multiple-parameters-call-back-in-moq) SO question.