# Mock method with IDbDataParameter params

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am trying to unit test a function that uses a dependency with some interface.
I want to mock this interface using moq. The interface has a function like this:

```
int Command(CommandType commandType, string commandText, params IDbDataParameter[] parameters);
```

The 'normal' class that implements the interface will use the IDbDataParameter parameters and set some values on them. These values are then used in the function that calls the command function on the interface. Does anyone know how I setup the mock object so when the command function is called on the mock object it will set the values on the IDbDataParameter it receives as input?

So the function I want to test and in which the Command function is called looks like this:

```
var pInput = DbDataParameter();
var pOutput = DbDataParameter();

Dependency.Command(Type, Name, pInput, pOutput);

if (pOutput.Value != null)
{
    Do Something
}
```

I have tried using the callback function like below but that does not work.
The array variable is an array where the values are set like they are needed in the function to test.

```
Mock.Setup(o => o.Command(It.IsAny<CommandType>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<IDbDataParameter[]>())).
            Callback<CommandType, string, IDbDataParameter[]>((c, s, p) => p = array);
```

Comment: If you are mocking the class that implements your `Command` method then your Command method implementation is gone. It will work as a Spy, so can only verify the calls (times, parameters). There is no such logic that modifies IDbParameter[]. What do you want to test?

Comment: I know but the function also uses that value set in the parameters by the 'normal' function. So to test this functionality I need the mock to set these values.

Comment: Then this is a duplicate topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147221/how-to-change-input-parameter-in-moq

Comment: Okay so I edited my question with the way I setup the mock. This is how it is done in the question you posted. It is still not giving the array with the set values in the function I am testing. Could it be that the Setup function is incorrect, so the callback is not called?

Comment: The setup seems correct for me.

You can also give it a try to the following:
```Mock 
  .Setup(o => o.Command(It.IsAny<CommandType>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<IDbDataParameter[]>()))
  .Returns((CommandType type, string text, params IDbDataParameter[] parameters) => { parameters= expectedParameters;  return 0;});```

Comment: That gives the same result.

Comment: Can you show me please how you call the Command mock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the answer to my own question. The problem was that you cannot assign a value to the array directly so `(p = array)` did not work. However it is possible to assign a value to the values in the array. So `(p[1] = array[1])` did work. So for example:

```
    Mock.Setup(o => o.Command(It.IsAny<CommandType>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<IDbDataParameter[]>())).
        Callback<CommandType, string, IDbDataParameter[]>((c, s, p) => 
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
            {
                p[i] = array[i]);
            }
        });
```