# Mock a method array argument using Moq

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, moq

Using Moq4, I am trying to replace one of the method's argument as done with a `List<string>` [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147221/how-to-change-input-parameter-in-moq). However, using the `byte[]` type, I am not able to change the value. **Any idea or solution?**

- The code

  ```
   public class SomeObject
   {
       public virtual void DoSomething(byte[] array, int offset, int count) { }
   }

   [Fact]
   public void SomeTest()
   {
       // Arrange
       byte[] expectedArray = new byte[] { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
       var mock = new Mock<SomeObject>();

       mock.Setup(so => so.DoSomething(It.IsAny<byte[]>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
           .Callback<byte[], int, int>(
           (buffer, offset, count) => { buffer = new byte[] { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }; }
           );

       var target = mock.Object;
       var array = new byte[64];

       // Act
       target.DoSomething(array, 0, 10);

       // Assert
       Assert.Equal(expectedArray, array);
   }
  ```
- Obtained output

> Message:
> Assert.Equal() Failure
> Expected: Byte[] [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
> Actual:   Byte[] [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...]

Comment: I think you want to use `Returns()` not `Callback()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning `new byte[] { 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };` to the lambda parameter creates a **`new`** object, which is different than the original `byte[64]` that you created beforehand.

The only way your lambda can modify the values passed by reference is **using** that reference, not replacing it. i.e: `buffer[0] = 5`.

If `SomeObject` is your own code (and you should not mock what you don't own), consider a signature that *returns* the array instead, in line with [CQS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation). You could then just use `.Returns()` in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your help @istepaniuk. You're saying _you should not mock what you don't own_ and that's exactly what I am trying to achieve by mocking [Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)](https://github.com/jcurl/SerialPortStream/blob/43a5be1e2a43adfe799280db7ad17667567d3944/code/ISerialPortStream.cs#L537) used within the tested class. Is there any other way to test a communication class without mocking the serial implementation (should build in a [pipepline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_pipelining) too)?

Comment: @fofolevrai it depends on your context. Normally, your logic should be covered by *unit* tests (in isolation) and only depend on *abstractions* (your own agnostic interface of what this library does). Then, to test, you simply mock such interface. That means that you would need a wrapper for this library that implements the interface. This wrapper can also be tested separately to make sure it works as expected (integration test), but that is especially difficult for something like a serial port.